# How can I configure MTurk to send OTP codes by email instead of SMS?

Tags: account-management, mturk

I have an Amazon Mechanical Turk (MTurk) Requester account that sends OTP codes by SMS.

How can I configure it so that codes are sent instead to my email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible according to Amazon Mechanical Turk's Requester support:

> I'm sorry for any inconvenience, but is is not currently possible to have MTurk OTPs to email addresses instead of your registered phone number.